# Flexible layout using interface builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I want to achieve this layout that will resize width in landscape mode and will keep all spaces(gaps) as defined. So single column of `UITextView` in one row there are two which should take half of the width left when left right and in between gaps are deducted.

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|                     <y>                     |
|    +-----------------------------------+    |
|    |                                   |    |
|    +-----------------------------------+    |
|    +-----------------------------------+    |
|    |                                   |    |
|    +-----------------------------------+    |
|    +----------------+ +----------------+    |
|<x> |        50%     | |      50%       | <x>|
|    +----------------+ +----------------+    |
|    +-----------------------------------+    |
|    |                                   |    |
|    +-----------------------------------+    |
|                                             |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

I tried for a long time checking different constrains like width <= 280 and width >= 280 - both with the same results.

Can someone write step by step what to do to have this layout? Does it matter that it is inside the `UIScrollView`?

The structure is:

```
View
   Scroll View
      Content View
           Round Style Text Field
           Round Style Text Field
           View
               Round Style Text Field
               Round Style Text Field
           Round Style Text Field
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an other view around what you want to center.

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                     <y>                       |
|    +-------------------------------------+    |
|    |+-----------------------------------+|    |
|    ||                                   ||    |
|    |+-----------------------------------+|    |
|    |+-----------------------------------+|    |
|    ||                                   ||    |
|    |+-----------------------------------+|    |
|    |+----------------+ +----------------+|    |
|<x> ||        50%     | |      50%       || <x>|
|    |+----------------+ +----------------+|    |
|    |+-----------------------------------+|    |
|    ||                                   ||    |
|    |+-----------------------------------+|    |
|    +-------------------------------------+    |
|                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

It's easy to center a view within another view.

```
View
    Scroll View
        Content View
            View
                Round Style Text Field
                Round Style Text Field
                View
                    Round Style Text Field
                    Round Style Text Field
                Round Style Text Field
```

Comment: How can this help me to have all textfields to use all available widths (minus left and right gaps)? What constraint setup I should do in interface builder?